# "Linking" two fullcalendars jquery and dynamically changing each other's dates

Tags: jquery, date, fullcalendar

I have 2 fullcalendars in my page. The one is a small only month view and the other one s a large one with only week and day views. The goal is that the user picks a date from the small one and immediatelly this shows in the big one (either in week or day view). The user can also  navigate with the prev and next buttons of the big one and the changes must reflect in the small one. The reason i am using two (I don't know if it is best practice) is because each day of mine has a lot of events, so lacking a "+ x more" show events option I had to find a way to "solve" the problem day cells growing very big. Sο what i have is the following

html

```
<div id="small-cal"></div>
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
        ...some options here


    });
    $("#small-cal").fullCalendar({
        ...some options here
        dayClick:function(date,allDay){
            if (allDay){
                $("#calendar").fullCalendar('gotoDate', date); //Works big calendar goes to date in the view that is currently in.
            }
        }

    });
    $("#calendar .fc-button-next span).click(function(){
        //catching next clicked from big calendar
        var date = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getDate');
        $("#small-cal").fullCalendar('gotoDate', date); //Not working properly

    });
});
```

The reason that is not working is because click comes before new date is rendered in the big calendar so the date variable contains the today's date and not the tomorrow's. I know there is a method incrementDay but wasn't able to use it. Can I add 1 in my date object to make it go to the next page?

EDIT solved it using this:

```
$('#calendar .fc-button-next span').click(function(){
            var date = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getDate');
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
            console.log(date);
            $("#small-cal").fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
        });

    $('#calendar .fc-button-prev span').click(function(){
        var date = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getDate');
        date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
        console.log(date);
        $("#small-cal").fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
    });
```

But now I get another "error". If i press button very fast repeatedly it won't change the date. It won't even log in the console. Like lagging from the large ammount of clicks. How can i overcome this?Is it a general javascript problem?

Comment: Try using a setimeout function in the onclick event, i have done that when i want to use the scroll to navigate months to prevent exponencial calls to the server.

Comment: with what parameters. I mean how much time?

Comment: What do you mean? [settimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Comment: Yes i know the function...I mean the time, What would be a good value for the time parameter, what would you recomend

Comment: Well it depends on the normal loading time for every prev next action.
If you think is 2 or 3 seconds, you will have to set like 4 seconds, before you can make the action of prev, next again.

Comment: nice solution still helpful

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. The best solution is to create your own button and hook it up to all calendars like this: (you can find this in the documentation)

```
$('#my-prev-button').click(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('prev');
    $('#small-cal').fullCalendar('prev');

});
$('#my-next-button').click(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('next');
    $('#small-cal').fullCalendar('next');

});

<div id='my-prev-button'>Previous Week</div>
<div id='my-next-button'>Next Week</div>
```

You will then obviously have to hide the default buttons